# Relation between equations of the form "Derivative" $f=0$

Tags: field-theory, mathematics, differential-equations, clifford-algebra, equations-of-motion

I'm currently taking an introductory course in QFT, and I've noticed that lots of equations in physics take the form of "Derivative" of a funcition equal 0. Some examples being the wave equation: $\Box u =0$, the Maxwell equations in vacuum: $d F=0$ and $ d  \star F=0$, the Dirac equations for massless particles $i{\not}\,\partial\psi=0$ and so on. Since these "derivatives" are not the usual one dimensional derivative the result is not trivial, but just as the Sturm-Liouville theory deals with equations of the type $\mathcal{L} u =\lambda u$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is an arbitrary linear differential operator, I wondered if there was a similar theory that deals with these types of equations, relating them even though they act on different spaces and objects.

My course isn't very oriented towards the mathematical formalism of QFT, and I also thought that maybe ${\not}\partial$ isn't just a useful shortcut as I was told, but some sort of "Covariant" or "Generalized" derivative.

Note that I'm not including the general Dirac equation or the Klein-Gordon's equation since they have a mass term. They can be expressed as $\mathcal{L}\phi=0$ with $\mathcal{L}=i{\not}\partial-m$ but I don't think they fulfill the condition of being "derivative"-like.

---

To recap, my main concerns are:

1. Is there some deep explanations on why so many equations are of the form "Derivative"$f=0$, or is just that almost any equation can be rearranged to look this way?
2. Is there a theory that study these types of equations $\mathcal{L}u=0$, analogous to Sturm-Liouville? Do they share any common structure?
3. Are ${\not}\partial$ or $\Box$ just shortcuts or is there more to it? This question is motivated because just as four vectors are usually presented just as notation to write equations in a more compact way, they turn out to be quite fundamental objects.

Comment: All of your examples are wave equations with no sources... they have the form "derivative $=$ zero" because that ensures that when there no sources, "field $=$ zero" is a solution. The moment you consider a theory with actual interactions, you'll get extra terms on the right-hand side. In other words, the equations you learned all look simple because a QFT course will start with the simplest equations.